# Looking for a way to use merge join on two sorted lists

Tags: python, merge

Consider the following two lists

```
list_1 = [(288645, [300]),
          (249594, [300, 305]),
          (288647, [300, 310]),
          (249587, [300])]

list_ 2 = [(290, [786020, 601157, 827251]),
          (300, [814888, 829081, 365044]),
          (305, [781169, 826323]),
          (310, [819361, 639450])]
```

Some Important things to note:

`list_1` is sorted on `list_1[1]`:

```
list_1 = sorted(list_1_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
```

`list_2` is sorted in `list_2[0]`

```
list_1 = sorted(list_2_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[0])
```

for both lists, here is an example of the `list_dict`

```
list_dict = {288645: [300], 249594: [305, 300], 385623: [30563]}
```

Moreover, for both lists, `list[0]` is always a single element

I would like to create a join, where the elements in `list_1[1]` match the elements of `list_2[0]`. In our case, the temporary result would like this:

```
list_3 = [(288645, [814888, 829081, 365044]),
          (249594, [814888, 829081, 365044]),
          (288647, [814888, 829081, 365044]),
          (249587, [814888, 829081, 365044])]
```

Some issues I have encountered is that both elements in either list can arrive multiple times. So using the popular sort merge join (since the lists are already sorted) would not work. Checking if one element is bigger than the other would neglect that I think.
I am thinking about changing the structure completely, because this causes too much of a headache maybe. Any ideas or advice?

Comment: Your code references an undefined `list_1_dict`. Please add it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your output, here is my solution:

```py
list_3 = []
for d1key, d2keys in list_1:
    d2values = list_2_dict.get(d2keys[0], None)
    if d2values:
        list_3.append((d1key, d2values))
list_3
```

Notes

- You don't need to convert `list_2_dict` to `list_2`
- `d2values` is what you want, if the key from `list_1` exists in `list_2_dict`

Comment: ty! Since it is supposed to mimic a sort merge join, sorting would be great!